# Display some very basic data using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an API and a UI page.

The API exposes a PDF document in a GET request. The controller response is byte[] with `@produces=application/pdf`

I want to display that pdf in my UI in a iframe for example. So I did this code:

```
  document.querySelector("iframe").src = apiBaseURL + "/retrievePDF/" + pdfID;
```

Works great but I realize I have an issue. **The user needs direct access to the API when using this direct link**, otherwise he cannot get the PDF document.

How can I do this code withut it?

Comment: any help please? Maybe I need to load the data with http.get and do some magic to display it on iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a proxy on your server that retrieves the pdf from the API and forwards it to the user.